# Eyes are missing from a 3D model I bought on Sketchfab when using GLTF format

Tags: gltf

I bought this 3D model from Sketchfab:
https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/robin-bird-0a93168c1a2b4de0a9eebbffc9642d61

This is what the model looks like when I import the GLTF file into Blender
[image: 3D model inside Blender]

This is what it looks like with the materials
[image: 3D model inside Blender with materials]

For some reason the eyes seem to be missing. But when I open the .blend file the eyes are there (see image below)
[image: opening the .blend file]

Since I need this 3D model for a project in another software which only supports FBX and GLTF files (GLTF works best) I need to use the GLTF file formar for my project.
Why do the eyes disappear? How can I solve this problem?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you tested the glTF in a viewer to check if the eyes appear there?

Comment: @scurest They don't appear in the 3D Viwer from Microsoft

Comment: Why don't you use the blend file and export the bird as glTF 2.0 or FBX? (File > Export ...)

Comment: @Blunder I've already tried but the GLTF file ist just grey. I looked into the the "UV Editing" tab and the material is there. But the 3D model is grey when exporting it in GLTF format. (I am a complete rookie in blender for your information). How do I apply the material which already is in the "UV Editiing" tab?

Comment: When you exported the bird the eyes had been there but they were just grey, right? In screenshots 1 &2, it looks like the eyes are missing/not visible at all. That's why I ask. Do you mean "Shading" workspace? There you can inspect the materials. The "UV Editing" is for the UV maps. Maybe post a screenshot of the bird in wireframe mode (key Z) and the material of the eyes.